# Create documentation for an R project

Tags: r, documentation

I would like to create documentation for my R code. The code is a part of an R project but not of a package. Is there a way I can display documentation for code not in a package using the built-in help viewer without creating a full package?

Comment: Sure, I agree. You can go on.

Comment: Documenting code properly needs vastly more effort than building a package. I don't really understand why anybody would do the former but not the latter.

Comment: @Roland While I agree in spirit - in practice some people have different workflows. If they're willing to write documentation without changing their workflow to accommodate creating a full package then that's fine with me.  I'll also say that while I think package creation is a lot easier than it used to be it's still a formidable hurdle for those that haven't done it before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use roxygen style comments above your functions if you're fine with keeping your documentation in the code files directly. You wouldn't easily be able to view you documentation using the typical `?your_function` syntax though.  There might be a way around that with some hacks to generate the documentation and place them somewhere in the help search path but that seems like more work than necessary.

If you're willing to include the roxygen2 style documentation inside the function you can get the nice `?your_function` syntax to view the documentation if you're willing to load the `docstring` package.  It's a package I wrote pretty much exactly for your use case - where you have code you want to document but haven't either taken the time or don't care to place it in a package.  I suggest either reading the README on [the github page for docstring](https://github.com/Dasonk/docstring) or view the vignette provided on the [cran page for docstring](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/docstring/index.html).

Here's an example session using docstring:

```
library(docstring)

square <- function(x){

    #' Square a number
    #'
    #' Calculates the square of the input
    #'
    #' @param x the input to be squared

    return(x^2)
}

# This will display the documentation for square
# just like any other help file would be displayed
?square
```